# Monotone convergence theorem for non-Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The Monotone convergence theorem:

> If $f_i: X\rightarrow[0, \infty]$ are $\mu$-measurable functions such
>   that $f_i\leq f_{i+1}$ then 
>   $$ \int_X \lim_{i}f_id\mu = \lim_{i}\int_X f_id\mu $$

We know it holds for the Lebesgue measure $\mu$. I want to ask are there any requirements on the measure $\mu$? Are there any other example measures that it doesn't hold? On what conditions of $\mu$, it can/can't hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't. Fatou, MCT and DCT hold for all $\sigma$-additive measures. See for instance the chapters on measure theory in Royden's *Real Analysis*, or any book that treats measure theory.

Comment: @Masacroso $\sigma$-additive, not $\sigma$-finite.